# Vim SQLComplete OMNI completion in Windows

Tags: sql, vim, omnicomplete

I've recently started using VIM (7.2) in Windows and have been trying to use the OMNI completion feature when editing SQL.

When at the start of a new line it appears to work fine. For example, if I am in insert mode and type:

```
se <C-C>a
```

then the word 'select' appears. If I then try and use OMNI completion on any other word on the same line then I get the 'Pattern not found' error.

I get the same error if, when on a new line, I type a space before typing the ' se'.

Is this the intended behavior? Or is there something I need to configure to make this work?

Comment: Under linux completion works fine for me. I can't test windows right now. Are you sure you mean <C-C>? I do insert completion with <C-N>(which is mapped to ,,)

Comment: Hi. Yeah, I'm using the SQLComplete plugin (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1572) that came as part of the standard Vim installation for Windows. <C-C>a is one of the default key mappings for OMNI completion with this particular plugin.

Comment: to get rid of this issue you can use version 7.0 of the sqlcomplete.vim plugin.
Have a look at http://old.nabble.com/SQL-completion-bug--td27064554.html and download version 7.0 from svn. Frank